# Integration with Shibboleth using WIF

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, wif, saml, shibboleth

I need to support SSO using `SAML 2.0` for my portal(`SP-initiated SSO` and `SP-initiated SLO` profiles). I have `Shibboleth` Server as `IdP` and now I need to create or use existing `SP` using C#.

Is it possible to implement `SP` for integration with Shibboleth using `WIF`, or I need to find other solutions?

Also any other info about integration with `Shibboleth` using C# will helpful.

Comment: I'm not exaclty sure if it works or not, but did you just try to use the identity and authorization tool to generate a web.config?

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio extension named "Identity and Access Tool"?

Comment: Yup, I was referring to that.

Answer (score 1):

WIF = WS Federation

Shibboleth = SAML

They don't interact so you can't use WIF out the box.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) and the links in that article.

Or you can do it via:

RP --> WIF --> ADFS --> SAML --> Shibboleth

Refer: [AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide: Federation with Shibboleth 2 and the InCommon Federation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: WIF is the Windows Identify Framework, which is in no way exclusive to WS Federation. WIF has baked-in support for WS Federation, but it also has baked-in support for SAML 2.0.

Comment: Actually, WIF stands for Windows Identity Foundation. Yes it supports WS-Fed only. It has SAML tokens but does NOT support the SAML protocol.